# My while loop is infinite even when using digits with isdigit()

Tags: python

Why is my while loop infinite when using bob and (5 for example)? New to python so if this is too basic of a question.

```
from splashkit import *

def read_string (prompt):
    write_line(prompt)
    result = read_line()

    return result

def read_interger (prompt):
    line = read_string(prompt)

    while not line.isdigit():
        print("Please enter a whole number")
        line = read_string(prompt)

    return int(line)

name = read_string("Enter your name: ")
age = read_interger("Enter your age: ")

print("Hello", name)
print("Aged: ", age)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wild guess... (the documentation of `read_line()` doesn't say much about what the function does).

The problem is that the line read also contains the newline `'\n'` character and therefore `.isdigit()` is going to be always false because, as the documentation says, the string must be not empty and ALL the characters in the string must be digits.

You can chage the input to `result = read_line().strip()` to solve this problem as it will remove the ending newline character.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how you discovered that the read_line() contained a \n?
Was it just an assumption that it would look silly format wise to not have a new line? or did you actually find it in the splashkit syntax somewhere?

Comment: Just read your edit, I assume it was just from a guess then. And yes, the documentation for splashkit is fairly bad.. haha. Thank you!

Comment: I discovered now what `splashkit` is and indeed the documentation doesn't say anything. I deduced what the problem was by reasoning (didn't install it). To say it all I don't think it's a good idea to use something like splashkit to learn programming with python...

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree. It's part of a silly (out-of-touch) programming class at uni @6502